# Cannot focus a Button in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility

I have a simple view like this. In the emulator, when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> on the keyboard, nothing happens. There's no indication that the button in focused, and the `onClick` is not called when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

NOTE: This is for [accessibility](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation), i.e., those who cannot use their fingers to tap and need an indicator that the button has focus, or those who use the app in a tablet + keyboard.

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        MaterialTheme {
            Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                Button(onClick = { println("clicked") }) {
                    Text(text = "A Button")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help. The Compose version is 1.0.5.

By the way,

1. I've read almost all pages of Compose documentation in Android Developers, including [Accessibility in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/accessibility), but I cannot find any useful information that solves my simple problem.
2. Compose `TextField` could receive focus either by pressing Tab or arrow keys.
3. I've also tried to place a View Button and a Compose Button side by side, only ViewButton could receive focus.

#### Update

```kotlin
    val iSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val focused by iSource.collectIsFocusedAsState()
    val pressed by iSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
    Button(
        onClick = { println("clicked") },
        Modifier.focusable(interactionSource = iSource),
    ) {
        Text(text = "A Button (focused=${focused}, pressed=${pressed})")
    }
```

This way, "focused" become true when I navigate by using arrow keys (Up/Down), but:

1. There's no focused indication.
2. Pressing Tab still doesn't work.
3. When it's focused, pressing Space or Enter doesn't trigger the onClick listener.

Comment: Why are you bringing up a keyboard when all you have is a button?? Makes no sense. You tap on a button with your finger, regardless whether the app runs in the emulator or on a real device. You don't use a keyboard and therefore makes no sense to have focus. Besides, in the emulator you still use a mouse to tap on the button.

Comment: @Johann it's what's called "accessibility", you create an app that enables users to interact without using their finger tap, for example those who cannot use their hands or those who cannot see or those who simply use a tablet + keyboard. And I emulate it by using Tab in my keyboard.

Comment: You can read more about it in https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation

Comment: I know what accessibility is. I worked on an app with accessibility. Your post didn't mention accessibility. I added some text to indicate this. Please be more specific in the future. Thanks.

Comment: I've added android-accessibility as a tag before, I thought it was enough. Thanks for adding that info in the question content.

Comment: I assume that you've covered all the accessibility material at: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/accessibility. Have you tried getting focus on a real device by toching (not tapping) it with your finger? If it works there but not in the emulator, then there is probably an issue with the emulator and Compose. Google tends to put low priority on supporting accessibility, especially for a new framework.